# How to correct projection of tiff in R using another tiff image

Tags: r, gis

I currently have over 200+ tiff files with the projection skewed and 1 tiff file with correct projection . I want to change the projection of the wrong ones based on the correct one. how do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you following a particular format convention (e.g. GeoTIFF)? Are all the files expected to have identical projection?  Is there any clear way to determine the nature of the skew in the other files?

Comment: `terra::mask`,  `<- terra::mask(my_skewed_tiff, my_good_tiff)`, values in skewed are allocated across good_tiff geometry/crs/res, etc. These tiffs have same extent? or it is just projection.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen yes its GeoTIFF. all files are expected to have identical projection. the skewed are rotated and have no crs. I have received a reference  to correct these.

Comment: @Chris the tifs are of same extent and the crs will be allocated using the reference tif.

Comment: `my_skewed_tifs <- list.files(where, full.names=T)`, `correct_tifs <- list()`, `for (k in 1:length(my_skewed_tifs)) { correct_tifs[[k]] <- terra::mask(my_skewed_tifs[[k]], my_good_tif) }` should serve.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the advice but it throws this error: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘mask’ for signature ‘"character", "character"’

Comment: What does `class(my_skewed_tifs[[1]])` and `class(my_good_tif.tif)` show?